# Emacs-Cider nrepl warning

Tags: emacs, clojure, cider

I have installed and setup Emacs for clojure using [this](http://www.braveclojure.com/basic-emacs/) wonderful tutorial. If i start the cider using `M-x cider-jack-in` the repl starts and is very nice! Now i read [here](https://github.com/clojure-emacs/cider) that a min `project.clj` should be `{:user {:plugins [[cider/cider-nrepl "0.9.1"]]}}`, i change my project.clj in .lein deirectory (which is "0.8.1") to "0.9.1" and when i start repl again i get this warning:

`WARNING: The following required nREPL ops are not supported: 
inspect-start inspect-reset
Please, install (or update) cider-nrepl 0.8.1 and restart CIDER
WARNING: CIDER's version (0.8.1) does not match cider-nrepl's version (0.9.1)`

Any idea how can i fix this?

Answer (score 3):

Your CIDER (the Emacs application) is version 0.8.1, not your `cider-nrepl`. Update CIDER to 0.9.1 (e.g. from the MELPA Stable repository) and the warning will disappear.

Comment: I know im late. but how do i do this. You are explaining the error, which i deduced correctly. meaning i know i have to update cider within emacs. but i cant find how to do this